# Update URL like jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

What methods does jQuery mobile use to update the URL without having the browser re-navigate to that URL? That is, how can I just edit the url string without altering the page and it's DOM and stay on the exact same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery uses some new history object methods that are present in HTML5.

from mozilla

> HTML5 introduced the history.pushState() and history.replaceState() methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries, respectively. These methods work in conjunction with the window.onpopstate event.

You can read up more on it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Check out [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) for a script allowing this API to work in older browsers.